# odoo 12 : How to calculate versatility index

Tags: python, odoo

I have 2 models : 
The first ('hr.polyvalence')

```
 class Polyvalence(models.Model):
        _name = 'hr.polyvalence'
        job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job', string='Job')
        skill_id = fields.Many2one('hr.skill', string='Skills')
        weight = fields.Integer(string='Weight')
```

example :

```
Job   | skills |  weight
------|------- |--------
 job1 | skill1 |3
------|--------|--------
      | skill2 |2
------------------------
 job2 | skill1 |1
------|--------|--------
      | skill3 |2
```

The second  (_inherit = 'hr.employee')

```
class EmployeePolyvalence(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'hr.employee'

        rate_skill = fields.Float(string="Rate", compute="_compute_rate_skill")

        @api.multi
        @api.depends('job_id', 'employee_skill_ids')
        def _compute_rate_skill(self):
            somme = 0
            for rec in self:
                if rec.job_id and rec.employee_skill_ids:
                    for skill in rec.employee_skill_ids:
                        if skill.level == '0':
                            level = 1
                        elif skill.level == '1':
                            level = 2
                        elif skill.level == '2':
                            level = 3
                        elif skill.level == '3':
                            level = 4
                        versatility = self.env['hr.polyvalence'].search([('job_id', '=', rec.job_id.id)])
                        if versatility:
                            weight = versatility.weight
                            rate = level * weight
                            somme += rate

            rec.rate_skill = somme
```

example :

```
Employee  | skills |  level
----------|------- |--------
employee1 | skill1 |1
----------|--------|--------
          | skill2 |3
----------|--------|---------
```

I want to calculate Versatility index with these 2 formulas:

```
 *Score of employee1:     
      job1=  (1*3 + 3*2) / (3+2) = 1.8    Sum (level*Weight) / Sum(Weight)
      job2=.....= 2
      job3=.....= 3                                 
 *Versatility index= (3+2+1.8)/ (3*3) = 75 %   Sum (Job Note) /( Number of Jobs * 3)
```

But when adding more than one skill in hr_polyvalence, I get an error raise Value error("Expected singleton: : %s" % self
ValueError: Expected singleton:hr.polyvalence(15,16)

Can someone help me please to get the correct calcul ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're getting multiple records. So try to replace this code,

```
versatility = self.env['hr.polyvalence'].search([('job_id', '=', rec.job_id.id)])
for vers in versatility:
    weight = vers.weight
    rate = level * weight
    somme += rate
```

Thanks

Comment: what about getting sum of weight ? It must be in the loop for ?

`somme_weight += weight`

 `rec.rate_skill = somme/somme_weight`

Comment: please clear your question, this much no gets at all. Yes for to weight sum you have to define the weight = 0 above the loop and assign it.